# Selenium drag and drop not working in angular js

Tags: angularjs, selenium, drag-and-drop

i have a test to automate drag and drop item in angular Js application page. When i click on source element and drag it my destination element xpath is getting changed.

I tried to use selenium action class with below code , but it didn't work for me.

Code Example 1

```
//CustomListItemElement = source element
// MainPanelElement = destination element

var action = new Actions(_webDriver);
 action.DragAndDrop(CustomListItemElement, MainPanelElement);
 action.Build().Perform();
```

Code Example 2

```
var action = new Actions(_webDriver);
  action.MoveToElement(CustomListItemElement);
  action.ClickAndHold(CustomListItemElement);
  action.MoveByOffset(240, 52);
  action.MoveToElement(MainPanelElement);
  action.MoveByOffset(799, 53);
  action.Release(MainPanelElement).Perform();
```

there is no error and test pass. it drags the element to destination , but didn't release it. (i think because destination xpath changeafter dragging it)

can someone help me with this please?

Updated:
 Source Element:

```
<li class="bar-list-item ng-scope drag-list-tool-item" ng-repeat="toolItem in toolboxItems | filter:filterFunction" drag-list-tool-item="toolItem" draggable="true">
```

Destination Element:

```
<ul drag-list="day.Items" drag-list-id="day.AgendaID" create-from-tool="createAgendaItem(itemType)" on-item-added="onItemAdded(index, item, $index)" on-item-moved="onItemMoved(fromIndex, toIndex, item, $index)" class="bar-list drag-list ng-scope">
            <!-- ngRepeat: item in day.Items -->
</ul>
```

After source element drag in to destination element it's changed to below.

```
 <ul drag-list="day.Items" drag-list-id="day.AgendaID" create-from-tool="createAgendaItem(itemType)" on-item-added="onItemAdded(index, item, $index)" on-item-moved="onItemMoved(fromIndex, toIndex, item, $index)" **class="bar-list drag-list ng-scope list-drag-over"**>
            <!-- ngRepeat: item in day.Items -->
</ul>
```

Comment: can you share html structure of source and destination?

Comment: Hey Dev, i have updated HTML code for source and destination element

Comment: Anyone able to solve this issue please?